# Showing that all closed sets are $G_{\sigma}$ Sets

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I am trying to prove that all closed sets are $G_{\sigma}$ sets. I think I have the key idea on how to execute a proof but I am a bit puzzled on how to avoid the few logical pitfalls when it comes to the nature of infinite sequences.

To make sure we're on the same page, the definition of a $G_{\sigma}$ set, according to my textbook (*Understanding Analysis*, S. Abbott) is as follows:

**$G_{\sigma}$ Set:** A set is a $G_{\sigma}$ if it can be expressed as a countably infinite intersection of open sets.

The question in the textbook (3.2.15 a) for the curious) is as follows:

> (a) Show that a closed interval [a, b] is a $G_{\sigma}$ set.

**My proof outline:**
I've settled on the countably infinite intersection

$$H = \bigcap^{\infty}_{n = 1}\left(a - \frac{1}{n}, b + \frac{1}{n}\right),$$

I will also use the notation

$$H = \bigcap^{\infty}_{n = 1}(a_n, b_n),$$

Where $a_n$ and $b_n$ are convergent sequences $a_n = a - \frac{1}{n}$ and $b_n = b + \frac{1}{n}$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$. By the algebraic limit property, and the prior assumed axiom that $\frac{1}{n}$ converges to 0, we can also definitevely say $a_n \rightarrow a$ and $b_n \rightarrow b$

After a bit of thinking, this seemed like a likely candidate of an infinite intersection of open sets resulting in a closed set. Before tackling my half-finished proof, I'll give the general intuition. For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the lower bound $a_n$ will be just a little bit smaller (to the left on the number line) than a. Thus, we can safely say that for this given lower bound $a_n$, that a is included in $(a_n, b_n)$. In the proof I attempt to show that we can ALWAYS see that a is a member of $(a_n, b_n)$. I run into a bit of trouble later on but bear with me for now.

**Proof attempt**:

Let $a_n$ be the lower open bound. For some given $a_n$, $a_n = a - \frac{1}{n}$. For each "iteration" of $a_n$, define a point $X_n$ where $X_n = a_n + \frac{1}{n}$. We can determine that $X_n \in (a_n, b_n)$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Furthermore, by substituting our definition of $a_n$ into the definition of $X_n$, we see that

$$X_n = a_n + \frac{1}{n}$$
$$X_n = a - \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n}$$
$$X_n = a$$

So, $X_n$ is a constant value, $a$. From this, we see that $a$ is included in $(a_n, b_n)$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Using the same argument, we can see that $b$ is also included in $(a_n, b_n)$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Knowing that $a_n \rightarrow a$ and $b_n \rightarrow b$, we know that the interval $(a_n, b_n)$ converges to $(a, b)$. My question for finishing my proof is - how do we extend the proven fact that $a$ and $b$ are both included in $(a_n, b_n)$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ to prove some claim that $a$ and $b$ are both included in $(a, b)$? Because, if we are able to show this, we can show that the limit points of $(a, b)$ are all included within the set and it is therefore closed.

I'm just a bit confused on how to make that logical jump. Does anyone have any tips? I feel like I might have the answer right under my nose.

Thanks!

Comment: The standard lingo is "a $G_\delta$ set is a countable intersection of open sets." You might be thinking of $F_\sigma$? Or perhaps mixed up the definitions. For the proof, try doing double inclusion of $ \cap_{n=1}^\infty (a-1/n,b + 1/n)$ and $[a,b]$.

Comment: ah, whoops - I think I just zoned out while typing that. Will edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We show both inclusions. $H\supseteq [a,b]$ is clear, so let $x\in H$ be arbitrary. By definition, for every $n>0$ we have $a-1/n<x<b+1/n$. Thus, taking infimums and supremums, we obtain $a\le x\le b$, or that, $x\in[a,b]$.

---

To give more detail, we have $x<b+1/n$ for each $n>0$. Suppose for a contradiction that $x>b$, so that $x=b+\epsilon$ for $\epsilon>0$. By the [Archimedean principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property) there exists an integer $m>0$ with $\epsilon>1/m$, so that $x>b+1/m$, a contradiction. Thus, we must have $x\le b$. The proof for $x\ge a$ is similar.

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify what you mean by "taking infimums and supremums"? I'm familiar with the concepts of infimums and supremums but just a bit confused on what you mean by "taking" them - sorry if this is dumb, really new to real analysis so my understanding is still a bit rigid

Comment: Sorry, I meant $a-1/n<x<b+1/n$ for all $n$, so certainly $\sup_n a-1/n\le x\le \inf_n b+1/n$. This is essentially the same argument as what I give below.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I've accepted your answer as it makes a lot of sense, is simple, and works, but I'm just wondering - was my beginning-of-a-proof a wrong direction, or is there any way to augment my proof for it to work? Just wondering since I wasn't just looking for an answer to the question, but to see if my logic on my beginning-of-a-proof was correct  somewhat, or not.

Comment: I am not super sure what you are doing in the proof, since, for instance, you say "$a$ and $b$ are both included in $(a,b)$," which is certainly not true. The general strategy in proving the equality of sets is proving both inclusions.